# Get Output from Terminal Window IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, intellij-plugin

I am developing a plugin in Intellij to be used in Pycharm. One problem that I am currently facing is, how can I get the output from the IDE terminal after I execute some command. To execute a command I use the ShellTerminalWidget that creates a new tab in the IDE terminal and executes the command I want. But I need a way to read that output.

Thanks.

[Command Execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Quze2.png)

Comment: I don't know if this would work, but the first thing I would try is see if you can extend `ShellTerminalWidget` and override the `processTerminalBuffer`. That looks like it reads the output and processes it.

Comment: I think I can´t override the processTerminalBuffer. @Abby

Comment: Fair enough, then could you provide a minimal example of what you're currently doing? Then I'll try to help you from there.

Comment: Thanks @Abby I have attached an image to my post with the command I execute. So basically when i click in a button in my toolWindow i run that command that paste the command to be executed in the terminal IDE and execute it. Then produces the output that I am trying to read.

Answer (score 0):

It seems consoleFilterProvider extension is what you need.
A simple plugin example with the feature can be found here:
https://github.com/siosio/consoleLink

Comment: can you explain me how this could work? Thanks for your answer